# A Dynamic programming  problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, puzzle

Can anyone help me find an optimal Dynamic programming algorithm for [this problem](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/DINGRP/)

On the way to dinner, the CCC competitors are lining up for their delicious curly fries. The N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100) competitors have lined up single-file to enter the cafeteria.

Doctor V, who runs the CCC, realized at the last minute that programmers simply hate standing in line next to programmers who use a different language. Thankfully, only two languages are allowed at the CCC: Gnold and Helpfile. Furthermore, the competitors have decided that they will only enter the cafeteria if they are in a group of at least K (1 ≤ K ≤ 6) competitors.

Doctor V decided to iterate the following scheme:

```
* He will find a group of K or more competitors who use the same language standing next to each other in line and send them to dinner.
* The remaining competitors will close the gap, potentially putting similar-language competitors together.
```

So Doctor V recorded the sequence of competitors for you. Can all the competitors dine? If so, what is the minimum number of groups of competitors to be sent to dinner?
Input

The first line contains two integers N and K.
The second line contains N characters that are the sequence of competitors in line (H represents Helpfile, G represents Gnold)
Output

Output, on one line, the single number that is the minimum number of groups that are formed for dinner. If not all programmers can dine, output -1.

Comment: You should probably tag the question appropriately if you want to have some answers. `trick` is a very meaningless tag.

Comment: @kletoskletos - Is there a reason to use dynamic programming here? Since we are given the number of Helpfile programmers and the number of Gnold programmers, we can divide their numbers by the group number specified by Doctor V. The remaining programmers in either group need to be added to an already formed group so that it doesn't exceed groups of six. I guess that's where Dynamic programming comes into play. Interesting problem.

Comment: @sc_ray: I think you misread the problem. You need to find contiguous groups of at least K people and remove them from the line, in such a way that you can eventually remove all the people from the line. You can't reorder the line, you can only remove groups of like-minded programmers that happen to be next to each other.

Comment: @Null Set: In that case, how would you group the following sequence,GHHGHHGH for K>=2?

Comment: @sc_ray - you wouldn't, you'd print -1.

Comment: So basically the problem boils to finding out the longest substring with common characters but for sequences such as GHHGHHG where the G's are isolated, we need to find all the G's until it has reached the group limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd prefer not to solve an SPOJ problem in a practical manner for you, so take the following as an existence proof of a poly-time DP.

For K fixed, the set of strings that can dine is context-free. I'm going to use `g` and `h` instead of `G` and `H`. For example, for K = 3, one grammar looks like

```
S -> ε | g S g S g S G | h S h S h S H

G -> ε | g S G

H -> ε | h S H
```

The idea is that either there are no diners, or the first diner dines with at least K - 1 others, between any two of which (and the last and the end) there is a string that can dine.

Now use the weighted variant of [CYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) to find the minimum-weight parse, where nonempty S productions have weight 1, and all others have weight 0. For K fixed, the running time of CYK is O(N<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: So you are saying that i can solve the problem in O(kN^3) time using a general version of the CYK algorithm.

Comment: Yes, the grammar has size linear in k after conversion to Chomsky normal form.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know what Chomsky normal form is and how how to convert it.Actually it is the first time that i see this CYK algorithm but it looks quite similar to the matrix chain multiplication algoirthm. Actually i was thinking an algorithm that finds the optimal solution with every possible remaining dines and combines them.The base is the matrix chain multiplication algorithm and it takes an additional O(n^2) time for every ove for a total of O(n^5).Can you give a better description of your algorithm in a bottom up manner?

Comment: Chomsky normal form is described on Wikipedia. The idea is to have the right-hand side of each production either be at most one terminal or exactly two non-terminals. The naive version of CYK in essence tests whether each of O(n^2) substrings can be produced by each non-terminal. The case involving two non-terminals requires the algorithm to guess the midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The subproblem is the minimal groups needed to get everyone to dine for a given state of the line. There are a whole lot of possible line states but only a few that will actually be seen, so your memoization should probably be done with a hash map.

Here's some pseudocode.

```
int dine(string line){
    if(hashmap.contains(line)){
        return hashmap.get(line);
    }
    if(line.length == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    best = N+1;
    for(i=0;i<line.length;i=j){
        type = string[i];
        j = i+1;
        while(type == string[j]){
            j++;
        }
        if(j-i >= K){
             result = dine(string.substring(0,i-1) + string.substring(j,string.length));
             if(result > 0 && result < best){
                  best = result;
             }
        }
    }
    if(best == N+1){
         hashmap.insert(line, -1);
         return -1;
    }
    else {
         hashmap.insert(line, best+1);
         return best+1;
    }
}
```

If you already found answer for this line, return that answer. If theres no people in the line, you are already done and you don't need to form any more groups.

Assume you can't form any groups. Then try to prove this wrong by trying out all the contiguous groups of like-minded programmers in the line. If the group is big enough to get picked, see how many more moves it would take to get everyone in the resturaunt after removing this group. Keep track of the least moves needed.

If you couldn't find a way to remove all the groups, return -1. Otherwise, return the least moves needed after removing a group plus one to account for the move you made on this step.

Comment: Can you give the complexity of your solution and some more explanation?

Comment: @dosdos No clue on the complexity.

Comment: I believe your solution can get exponential in time.

Comment: I think this is exponential. Consider a string like `HGHGHGHG...` of length 100 and `k = 1`. That's going to make a lot of recursive calls I think.

Comment: @IVlad I think you may be right, but I feel like there isn't any other way to do it as DP that will always give the optimal answer. The order you pick the groups in is important, like for example with HHGGHH, K=2. There is a two move solution, and 4 three move solutions.

Comment: I implemented this in C# using `Dictionary` for a hash and it takes very long for a string of 40 characters constructed like I said in the previous comment. There has to be a way to do it, plenty of people have solved it on SPOJ. I'm not seeing it either yet, however.

Comment: @Null Set - well we are talking about creating 2^N sets for N elements and then extracting a few of the subsets. I am pretty sure for unrestrained inputs, it will be solvable in exponential time.

Comment: I think  of an algorithm similar to the matrix chain multiplication but i am not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

How about divide and conquer? Take a (removable) group somewhere near the middle, and the two groups either side of it, say ...HHHGGGGGHHHHH.... - now there's two possibilities. Either those 2 sets of H's dine in the same group, or they don't. If they dine in the same group, then those G's between them must be removed as a group of *precisely* those G's (so you may as well try that as your first move). If they don't, then you can solve for the left and right sublists separately. Either case, you've got a shorter list to recurse on.

Comment: Yes but what is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: I think perhaps an easier way of putting it would be that you're trying to mark the first and last elements of each removal. I'm sure it's got the potential to be exponential, but I don't think there's any way around that (you can construct some worst-case sequences) but hopefully your competition input will be kind :)

Comment: Actually i was thking an algorithm like matrix chain multiplication which goes like this.

Comment: Compress the initial sequence like this HHHGGHHH into 3 2 3 and then find the optimal way for every possible combination like the matrix chain multiplication.It works for the cases i tried but i am not sure if it works in general

Comment: This is an excellent problem. I'd be really interested in seeing what the 'clever' solution is.